# Azure App Proxy preauth cookie is causing application timeout

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am running my desktop app behind Azure App Proxy with preauth enabled. The desktop app connects to a server to fetch and update data. When running it directly, it runs fine; however, behind the Azure App Proxy, we get a timeout error after 10 minutes. Looking through the HAR network logs, the only cookie that has a 10-minute timeout is the AzureAppProxyPreauthSessionCookie.

Is there a way to avoid such timeouts without disabling preauth for that desktop app? The desktop app authenticates with a server through an embedded WebView2 window, and I can modify the desktop app or server implementation, so is there something that should be done on the desktop app or the server to integrate with Azure App Proxy?

I will try to enable the AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount in the embedded WebView2 and see if that helps in the specific case where the OS login and app login are the same, but it might not, and in any case, a more general solution would be preferable.